# gauss error function in vba (excel)

Tags: excel, vba, function

Is there an existing function or open source lib to create an gaussian error function in VBA (in Excel)? Note that this is a [mathematical function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and has nothing to do with failure handling!

Answer (score 1):

The *Gauss error function,* which is the integral of the normal distribution, is supported in **Excel 2013** by the worksheet function *=GAUSS()*

From **VBA** you would access it in the usual fashion

```
Dim x as Double
Dim y as Double
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Gauss(x)
```

.
.

[image]

Comment: Are these Worksheetfuncions language independent in VBA? In the Worksheet they must be named in the display language. In german that means GAUSSFEHLER (http://office.microsoft.com/de-de/excel-help/erf-HP005209077.aspx)